# Find the parametrization of the intersection of a plane and a sphere

Tags: calculus, parametrization, line-integrals

> Find the line integral of $\int y dx + z dy + x dz$ along the curve
> given by the intersection of $x+y=2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(x+y)$, in
> clockwise direction.

I think I'm not getting the correct parametrization from this, what I did was:

From $x+y=2 \to y=2-x \to x^2+(2-x)^2+z^2=4$

Completing the square I got $(x-1)^2+z^2=2$, a circle of radius $\sqrt2$ and center $(1, 0)$, so the natural parametrization I thought of was $(1+\sqrt2 \cos t, 1-\sqrt2 \cos t, \sqrt 2 \sin t)$.

But this might be wrong right? I think this parametrization is in counter clockwise direction right?

Also, the solutions say the parametrization should be $(1+ \cos t, 1- \cos t, \sqrt 2 \sin t)$, and I don't know how they got that (which is also in counter clockwise direction I think ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have,
$$x+y=2 \implies x^2+y^2 = 4 -2xy$$

Then,
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2(x+y) \implies z^2 = 2xy \implies (\sqrt2 x-\sqrt2)^2 + z^2 = 2$$

From this we get the parametrisation,
$$(x,y,z) = (1+ \cos t, 1-\cos t, \sqrt2 \sin t)$$

Also, a parametrisation is neither clockwise or counterclockwise. The direction is required for loop circumvention, as in whether you go across the loop in a clockwise or anticlockwise manner.

Comment: Don't curves in general have an orientation? Thats what was I trying to say. Also, thank you so much for you answer!!

Comment: No, orientation is only brought up when a closed curve, a loop, needs to be travelled around. Say an ellipse in the x-y plane, you can travel around it in clockwise or anticlockwise manner as seen from the z axis. But if you look at it from the negative z axis, the orientation gets reversed. So, a curve can never be assigned an orientation by itself